# if command 'activating' (for lack of vocabulary) when it shouldnt

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code

```
from time import sleep
import random
print("You spawn in your house")
def in_your_house():
    
    sleep(1)
    print("Where do you want to go in your house")
    sleep(1)
    where_to_go_in_your_house = input("There is three ways to go. Your bedroom. Your couch and out the door")
    if where_to_go_in_your_house == "bedroom" or "Bedroom":
        print("you travel upstairs to your bedroom")
        sleep(1)
        print("your wife isn't there. She's at another man's house. nothing to worry about")
        in_your_house()

    if where_to_go_in_your_house == "couch" or "Couch":
        print("you walk towards to your couch")
        sleep(1)
        print("your lazy son and cute dog is taking up the couch")
        sleep(1)
        print("you cannot sit down on your couch")
        in_your_house()

    if where_to_go_in_your_house == "outside" or "Outside" or "Outdoors" or "outdoors" or "door" or "Door":
        print("you walk outdoors")
        sleep(1)




in_your_house()
```

however no matter what I enter it will only do the if where_to_go_in_your_house == "bedroom" or "Bedroom": command. (i want in the end to do the outside code thats why its slightly different)

can anyone tell me why

Comment: `where_to_go_in_your_house == "bedroom" or "Bedroom"` should  be `where_to_go_in_your_house in {"bedroom", "Bedroom"}`. your statement is always `True` as `"Bedroom"` (a non-empty string) is truthy.

Comment: probably even nicer: `where_to_go_in_your_house.lower() == "bedroom"`.

Comment: thanks hiro. New to progamming so this really helped

Comment: no problem. welcome to stackoverflow!